# Python says function is not defined despite being defined just two lines above

Tags: python, function, if-statement, box2d

I have this class:

```py
class Demo():

    ############################### Drawing functions

    SCREEN_OFFSETX, SCREEN_OFFSETY = SCREEN_WIDTH/16, SCREEN_HEIGHT

    def fix_vertices(vertices):
        return [(int(SCREEN_OFFSETX + v[0]), int(SCREEN_OFFSETY - v[1])) for v in vertices]

    def draw_polygon(polygon, screen, body, fixture):
        transform = body.transform
        vertices = fix_vertices([transform * v * PPM for v in polygon.vertices])
        pygame.draw.polygon(
            screen, [c / 2.0 for c in colors[body.type]], vertices, 0)
        pygame.draw.polygon(screen, colors[body.type], vertices, 1)
    polygonShape.draw = draw_polygon
    ''''
    Do other stuff...
    ''''
```

and I run it using these lines of code:

```
Car = Demo()
if __name__ == "__main__":
    Car
    print("It Works")
```

But when I try to run it I got an error that fix_vertices_ is not defined... how can I fix this?

Thank you very much

P.S. and another subquestion... is it the correct way of calling this class using the

```py
if __name__ == "__main__"
```

syntax or is there a better way for example

```py
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(Demo)
```

Thank you very much

Comment: This doesn't answer your syntax error, but rather your second question. Statement `Car = Demo()` is being called unconditionally whether `__name__` is "\_\_main\_\_" or not. This is probably not what you want. Also the statement `Car` accomplishes nothing. You probably want: `if __name__ == "__main__": car = Demo()`

Comment: You really need a minimal, *reproducible* example here (See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), emphasis on the *reproducible*. You have constants such as `SCREEN_WIDTH` and data structures such as the `body` argument to `draw_polygon` (which is supposed to have a `transform` attribute) that are apparently defined elsewhere, but aren't accessible to us. We can't try out your example and see what happens at our end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But when I try to run it I got an error that fix_vertices_ is not defined... how can I fix this?

You've defined `fix_vertices` as a *method* but are trying to call it as a *free function*. Pick one or the other.

> P.S. and another subquestion... is it the correct way of calling this class using the
>
> ```
> if __name__ == "__main__"
> ```
>
> syntax or is there a better way for example
>
> ```
> if __name__ == "__main__":
>      main(Demo)
> ```
>
> Thank you very much

It's really not clear what your question is. `if __name__ == "__main__"` is useful to provide packages which are both importable and runnable, having a "main function" is not necessary but can be convenient for proper scoping.

Answer (score 0):

`Demo` is a class, if you are going to use a method of the class like `fix_vertices` inside another method of the class like `draw_polygon` you need to use the keyword `self.(method)` like  `self.fix_vertices` instead. Consider reading how to create classes.

Also the statement `if __name__ == '__main__':` should separate the declaration of functions and classes from the usage and instantiation of them. You should create a `Demo` object inside the `if` statement not before, so your module is not executing stuff when imported.

Comment: `self` isn't actually a keyword in Python. It will need to be added as an additional, first, parameter to each method, or more errors will be thrown.

Comment: @RobinZigmond totally true!